# put an element beside the body

Tags: css, z-index, overlapping

I have a body made of a linear gradient in order to have a grid squared background on my page,i need to put my div paragraph with text"celentano" beside my body,and so, behind my grid... obviously i can't achieive. nothing happen if i set my positions on relative neither absolute.

`

```
html {
  background:transparent;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: 33% 24vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#fd4e1e 2px,transparent 1px),linear-gradient(to bottom,#fd4e1e 2px,transparent 1px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 900;
}
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
grid-gap: 10px;}
.grid-item1{
  grid-column: 1;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  grid-row:1
}
.grid-item2{
  margin:0;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.grid-item3{
  margin:0;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.grid-item4{
  margin:0;
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 4;
}
.titolo{
  margin-top:11.90vw;
}`
```

here's the css:
https://codepen.io/olivia-celentano/pen/MWjXVQJ
here's the site:
https://oliviacelentano.com/

Comment: an advice: forget the idea to put things behind the body. Don't mess a lot with the body because you will have headaches especially dealing with background propagation since the background of the body won't stay on the body .. TLDR: create another element and put above everything

Comment: sorry i red too late your answer, thank for every udefull advice, i'm trying to apply this by making a div that stay on the others. do you know if it exist a service of tutor or something like a teacher on line that canfollow one's work on request ?

Comment: check this: https://www.codementor.io/html_css-experts

Comment: so prescious!thanks